# Can you create a string in a similar fashion to std::cout?

Tags: c++

The following statement pipes all sorts of output to the console as a single string of text

```
std::cout << "Hi, my name is " << name_as_string << " and I am " << age_as_int << " years old, while weighing " << weight_as_double << " kilograms.";
```

Can we use this same syntax to build a string in a string variable?  How is it done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream ss;
ss << "Hi, my name is " << name_as_string;
ss << " and I am " << age_as_int << " years old, while weighing ";
ss << weight_as_double << " kilograms.";

std::string str = ss.str();
```

You can also use `std::istringstream` for multiple input, and `std::stringstream` for both input and output.

```
std::string str = "1 2 3 4 5";
std::istringstream ss(str);
int i;
while( ss >> i) {
    std::cout << i;
}
```

Comment: Technically `std::ostringstream` would be more addecuate.

Comment: It seems to me to be a shame you can't just go std::string str = ss; on the last line. Presumably there is a good reason, do you know what it is ?

Comment: @BillForster: Implicit conversions are sometimes dangerous and often undesirable.

Comment: @GMan: Yeah I know but in this case the whole idea is to build something that you can convert to a string. Why not make it as easy as possible to do the conversion ?

Comment: @BillForster: 5 additional characters doesn't slow you down, isn't harder to read, and doesn't create unfindable errors.

Comment: Okay, basically sounds like "implicit conversions considered harmful", therefore avoided in std library. Haven't had problems with them myself but my experience tends to be more with implicit conversion of primitive types. So I will take on board this wisdom. Thanks.

Comment: @BillForster: If I have an object `mouse` which implicity converts to a `bool` to easily check if a mouse is attached to the computer, that suddenly makes this a valid expresion: `int height = mouse() + 7;`  Also, `std::cout << mouse();` will display `1` instead of giving an error.

Comment: @Mooing Duck Ok, but that's because bool implicitly converts to int. Does std::string implicitly convert to something else ?

Comment: @BillForster: if implicit casts were common, most projects would probably have some class implicitly convertible from a string.

Answer (score 2):

stringstream will rescue you here;

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream ss;

ss << stuff << to << output;

std::string s = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [std::ostringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/)

Answer (score 1):

By using `std::stringstream` :

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << "Hi, my name is " << name_as_string << " and I am " << age_as_int << " years old, while weighing " << weight_as_double << " kilograms.";
  std::cout<<ss.str()<<std::endl;
}
```